# how to move in an array of images (blobs) in Angular?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, ng-modal

I have an image gallery displayed on my page. I need to implement a modal for whenever the user clicks on the images. In the modal I need to show the full size of the selected image. Here is the problem: I have already made the modal work, but when I click on any of the gallery images, the modal shows all of them together in a single modal. I need the modal to only show the one that the user clicked on.

Please note that my webpage is based on AngularJS and PHP. I used [ngModal](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal) for this modal and that I'm new to using Angular (basically I know nothing, I'm learning), so please be patient with me. Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
readApp.controller('newsGallery', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {
      modalShown: false,
    }
    $scope.logClose = function() {
      console.log('close!');
    };
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
      $scope.myData.modalShown = !$scope.myData.modalShown;
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller='newsGallery'>
   <modal-dialog show='myData.modalShown' width='75%' height='80%' on-close='logClose()'>

    <div ng-repeat = "i in idsBlobs" >
      <img src="php/visualizar_archivo.php?id={{i.id}}">
         </div>
   </modal-dialog>

   <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
      <div class = "col-md-4" ng-repeat = "i in idsBlobs" >
        <div class="news-image" align="center">
           <img src="php/visualizar_archivo.php?id={{i.id}}" class = "img-responsive img-rounded" ng-click='toggleModal();'>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>                 
 </div>
```

Comment: Would it work to simply remove the ngRepeat on the div inside the modal?

Comment: No, the ng-repeat is the one that allows to load the images stored in the DB, without it, loads nothing

Comment: I meant the repeat in the modal, not the repeat below that (in the gallery)... see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have the image that the user clicked on shown in the modal is to introduce a scope variable e.g. `$scope.selectedImage`. Next, in the function *toggleModal()*, accept an argument for the image and set that scope variable to that argument.

```
$scope.toggleModal = function(image) {
    $scope.myData.modalShown = !$scope.myData.modalShown;
    $scope.selectedImage = image;
};
```

Next update the call to that function in the *ng-click* handler:

```
<img src="php/visualizar_archivo.php?id={{i.id}}" ng-click='toggleModal(i);' class = "img-responsive img-rounded">
```

Then in the modal markup, show that selected image.

```
<modal-dialog show='myData.modalShown' width='75%' height='80%' on-close='logClose()'>
  <img src="php/visualizar_archivo.php?id={{selectedImage.id}}">
</modal-dialog>
```

That way the modal will only show the image that the user clicked on, instead of all images in the list.

See a demonstration of this below.

```js
readApp = angular.module('readApp', ["ngModal"]);
readApp.controller('newsGallery', function($scope) {
  $scope.idsBlobs = [{
      "id": 'MA',
      "src": "http://www.animatedimages.org/data/media/96/animated-lighthouse-image-0032.gif"
    },
    {
      "id": "MU",
      "src": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/large-home/128/Museum-icon.png"
    }
  ];

  $scope.myData = {
    modalShown: false
  }
  $scope.logClose = function() {
    console.log('close!');
  };
  $scope.toggleModal = function(image) {
    $scope.myData.modalShown = !$scope.myData.modalShown;
    $scope.selectedImage = image;
  };
});
```

```css
.img-thumb {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//elliott.andrewz.org/cdn/ng-modal.min.js"></script>
<link href="//elliott.andrewz.org/cdn/ng-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="readApp" ng-controller="newsGallery">
  <modal-dialog show="myData.modalShown" width="75%" height="80%" on-close="logClose()">
    <img src="{{ selectedImage.src }}" />
  </modal-dialog>
  <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="i in idsBlobs">
      <div class="news-image" align="center">
        <img src="{{ i.src }}" class="img-responsive img-rounded img-thumb" ng-click="toggleModal(i);" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huge thanks... It seems like a really easy solution, but since I'm learning Angular I need to know how this works well.
Tanks again.